# Ngrams with non-symmetrical padding in NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, n-gram

The quad gram of the word *TEXT* is

```
>>generated_ngrams = ngrams('TEXT', 4, pad_left=True, pad_right=True, left_pad_symbol=' ', right_pad_symbol=' ')

>>list(generated_ngrams)
[(' ', ' ', ' ', 'T'), (' ', ' ', 'T', 'E'), (' ', 'T', 'E', 'X'), ('T', 'E', 'X', 'T'), ('E', 'X', 'T', ' '), ('X', 'T', ' ', ' '), ('T', ' ', ' ', ' ')]
```

According to me the output should have been `_TEX, TEXT, EXT__, XT__`. 
According to this website (http://cloudmark.github.io/Language-Detection/) the output is `_TEX, TEXT, EXT_, XT__, T___`
It also goes on to say "In general a string of length k, padded with blanks, will have k+1 bi-grams, k+1 tri-grams, k+1 quad-grams and so on."
Based on the output I got from Python I don't think that is valid.
Kindly explain.

Comment: When you say that, according to you, left and right padding should not be symmetric, what is your reasoning? Please explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Padding ensures that each symbol of the actual string occurs at all positions of the ngram. So for 4-grams there will be three padded ngrams of the last symbol, `E X T _`, `X T _ _`, and `T _ _ _`, etc. as your code shows you.

The website you link to adds *one* space on the left, then pads properly on the right. That's why the counts are different. This gives the same number of ngrams for all lengths. This is the corresponding Python code:

```
generated_ngrams = ngrams(" " + 'TEXT', 4, 
                          pad_left=False, pad_right=True, right_pad_symbol=' ')
```

Why it was done this way, only the author of the blog really knows. But one consequence of padding out on the right but not the left is that, as the blog points out, a given string of length `k` will produce a fixed number of n-grams (`k+1`) for any n-gram size `n`. The initial space doesn't contribute to this, but serves as a word boundary sign: ngrams that start with a space are word-initial.

Comment: Who knows? Read the blog you cited to see why. Or a textbook. The initial space is probably a word delimiter, the padding I explained already.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Since the answer has solved your problem, please "accept" it by clicking on the big check mark on its left to mark the question resolved.

Answer (score 4):

@alexis answer will provide you with the single-char left pad and multi-char right pad.

If we read the blogpost carefully:

> We will also append blanks to the beginning and end of strings in order to help with matching the beginning-of-word and end-of-word situations.
>
> We will represent this using the _ character. Given the word TEXT we would obtain the following N-Grams:

```
bi-grams _T, TE, EX, XT, T_
tri-grams _TE, TEX, EXT, XT_, T__
quad-grams _TEX, TEXT, EXT_, XT__, T___
```

**The motivation for non-symmetrical padding is unclear.**

Continuing with the blogpost:

> In general a string of length k , padded with blanks, will have k+1 bi-grams, k+1 tri-grams, k+1 quad-grams and so on.

From the NLTK implementation and symmetrical padding, it should be:

> A specifically, a string of length k symmetrical padding with blanks will yield `k + (n-1)` ngrams. For the case where the word is `TEXT`:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> from nltk import ngrams
>>> padded_ngrams = partial(ngrams, pad_left=True, pad_right=True, left_pad_symbol='_', right_pad_symbol='_')
>>> x = 'TEXT'

>>> list(ngrams(x, 2))
[('T', 'E'), ('E', 'X'), ('X', 'T')]
>>> len(list(ngrams(x, 2)))
3

>>> list(padded_ngrams(x, 2))
[('_', 'T'), ('T', 'E'), ('E', 'X'), ('X', 'T'), ('T', '_')]
>>> len(list(padded_ngrams(x, 2)))
5
>>> len(list(padded_ngrams(x, 3)))
6
>>> len(list(padded_ngrams(x, 4)))
7
>>> len(list(padded_ngrams(x, 5)))
8
```

To argue for symmetrical vs non-symmetrical padding, a principled way to test with a dataset and see the effects of the features in a classification task.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your insights. I cannot up vote your answer as I don't have any points to do so. Thank you, again.

Comment: No worries ;P I hope the answer helped you and possibly document it for future users.

Comment: How do I document it?

Comment: I meant to say hopefully this answer will be a good document for anyone asking similar questions on the padding conventions in `nltk` =)